# WooCommerce variable products discount not showing on single product page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using partially the code from this answer thread:

[Add the discounted percentage to variable product price range in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798284/add-the-discounted-percentage-to-variable-product-price-range-in-woocommerce/48798376#48798376)

Here the code I am using:

```
// Add the saved discounted percentage to variable products
add_filter('woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'add_sale_price_percentage', 20, 3 );
function add_sale_price_percentage( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ){
    // Strip html tags and currency (we keep only the float number)
    $regular_price = strip_tags( $regular_price );
    $regular_price = (float) preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $regular_price);
    $sale_price = strip_tags( $sale_price );
    $sale_price = (float) preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $sale_price);

    // Percentage text and calculation
    $percentage  = __('Save', 'woocommerce') . ' ';
    $percentage .= round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 );

    // return on sale price range with "Save " and the discounted percentage
    return $price . ' <span class="save-percent">' . $percentage . '%</span>';
}
```

It shows correct percentage of both simple & variable product for currency Indian INR.

But when change currency to USD , simple products shows correct percentage but variable products shows 0%.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have tested this code with different currencies and it works just fine for all product types…

Comment: I am using currency converter for multi currencies and when currency change from  INR to USD, then this error occurs.

Comment: This code is not made or tested to work with a third party plugin as your currency converter and **can't be enhanced more than it is actually.** So this currency converter is making trouble in some way that can't not be guessed by anybody and you didn't mention anything related to a currency converter plugin in your question.

Comment: I am using 'Woocommerce Currency Switcher' plugin.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec , When variable products have different prices & when select variation ,below the variations it shows selected variation's price with correct 'save %'
*see screenshot here >  https://ibb.co/cJwNhp